# SKSprite following CGMutablePath alignment

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgpath, skshapenode

I'm confused on what is going on here.  I know its supposed to be some coordinate shift, but when I use a circle for the path it traces it exactly.  If I use a curve as below this is the result I get.  I just want to draw the curve then have a sprite be able to trace the curve.  Any ideas what is wrong?

```
//  CGPathRef circle = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,400,400), NULL);

CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(circle, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(circle, NULL, 200, 200, 265, 20); 

SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:circle asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:1.0];
 SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];
[MySprite runAction:forever];
```

[image: Actual Particle Path vs SKShapNode]

Comment: did you try asOffset:YES ?

Answer (score 0):

Without using Maths to confuse you, the reason for the path as you see it is because the third and fourth parameters as defined by the CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint:

```
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, m, cpx, cpy, x, y)
```

are control points for the curve that arises as a result of the Math calculation done to obtain the curve defined given the parameters. So for example, given a curve that starts at (0,0) and ends at (0, 200) with a control point sitting at (100, 100), the highest point on that curve will actually sit around (100, 50). In other words, the top most part of the curve will go about half-way up on the y-axis to where the control point's y-coordinate is. So if you want the highest point of the curve to sit at (100, 100), then your control point's y-coordinate would sit around 200.

Of course this gets a bit more complex when the control points sits offset to the center of the curve, or when you have multiple control points making up the curve. Refer to this wikipedia page for a detailed working on curves/paths:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve